# Cypress: Test non-XHR request caused by submitting POST form

Tags: cypress

I am testing Vue application. In some cases my application have to submit(not just after click submit button but programmatically) POST form and redirect to 3rd party server with some body parameters. Like in [best practice](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites) written I am trying to avoid of using redirect to real server.

For my certain test it will be sufficient to just make sure that request was sent with certain parameters, but I don't now how to catch this body request parameters for assertion, because cypress does not allow to stub non-XHR requests and I can't do like this:

```js
cy.route('POST', '/posts').as('post')
cy.get("@post").should(req => {
  // check body params
});
```

I also thought about stub vue component method to intercept form submitting, but it only seems to work with global objects like Math.

I truly appreciate any new ideas how to test functionality like this.

Answer (score 1):

Since Cypress 5.1 you can stub other requests type using cy.route2()(https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#5-1-0).